# Cheapest way in aws to move/obtain a subset of files based on date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ksh

The main question I have is:
how can i move files based on a date range, without incurring client-side api calls that cost money?

Background:
I want to download a subset of files from an AWS S3 bucket onto a linux server but there are millions of them in ONE folder, with nothing differentiating them except a sequence number; and I need a subset of these based on creation date. (well actually, inside the files is an event timestamp, so I want to reduce the bulk first by creation date).

I have frankly no idea what costs I am incurring, everytime I do an ls on that dataset , e.g. for testing.

Right now I am considering:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "${S3_BUCKET}" --prefix "${path_from}" --query "Contents[?LastModified>='${low_extract_date}'].{Key: Key}"
```

but that is client-side if I understand correctly. So I would like to just move the relevant files to a different folder first, based on creation date.

Then just run aws S3 ls on that set.

Is that possible?

Because in that case, I would either:

1. move files to another folder, while limiting to the date range that I am interested in  (2-5%)
2. list all these files (as I understand, this is where the costs are created?) and subsequently, extract them (and move them to archive)
3. remove the subset folder

or:

1. sync bucket into a new bucket
2. delete all files I dont need from that bucket (older than date X)
3. run ls on the remaining set

or:
some other way?

And: is that cheaper than listing the files using the query?

thanks!

PS so to clarify: i wish to do a server-side operation to reduce the set initially and then list the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a good approach to this would be the following:

- If your instance is in a VPC create a VPC endpoint for S3 to allow direct private connection to Amazon S3 rather than going across the internet
- Move the object keys that you want, to include a prefix (preferably `Y/m/d`) e.g. `prefix/randomfile.txt` might become `2020/07/04/randomfile.txt`. If you're planning on scrapping the rest of the files then move it to a new bucket rather than in the same bucket.
- Get objects based on the prefix (for all files for this month the prefix would be `2020/07`

From the CLI you can move a file using the current syntax

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucketname/prefix/randomfile.txt s3://bucketname/2020/07/04/randomfile.txt
```

To copy the files for a specific prefix you could run the following on the CLI

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/2020/07 .
```

To get files on a specific date you can run the below

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket bucketname --query 'Contents[?contains(LastModified, `$DATE`)]'
```

The results of running this would need to be run via the CLI

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the actual issue here, is that all files have been dumped into the same container and were not moved away in time (initial load situation). So I have no idea how to obtain the correct ones, except by creation date.

Comment: thanks, I have added more details on what I am trying to achieve

Comment: The command you specified appears to be the best route to listing the files you want, unfortunately you cannot copy a subset of the files outside of using a prefix. So you could either move files to a new prefix and copy via prefix, or copy once from the output of files from the list objects function.

Comment: ah, ok, thanks for the info - so I wonder what order of magnitude of price are we talking about then? I am afraid to even test my software, knowing i am listing a set of at least 400k files .

Comment: OK so from my calculations the cost for listing all objects if there were 400,000 would be `$0.16`, as it is `$0.0004 ` per 1000 get requests. If you have a VPC endpoint and copy directly down to your server the price is `$0.02 per GB`. More information here: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: ALRIGHT! :D:D wow that has REALLY put things into perspective.... I was thinking at least $USD 10, or even up to $100 per call for millions of records.. thank you!! Now I can develop for performance without fear. Speaking of which... can these calls be sped up? It takes up to 10 minutes before I am getting a result on that query..

Comment: Glad thats helped a little :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217218/discussion-between-rusty75-and-chris-williams).